# ASP.Net MVC vs Web Forms what are the benefits of one over the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC versus WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837831/mvc-versus-webforms)

Was curious what the main benefits of going MVC over Web Forms.  I write everything in web forms currently but I already enforce a pretty strict separation on myself would I see any benefits from moving to MVC?

Currently I use jquery for my AJAX; calling Page Methods and Web Services.  I typically only use the Page Load handler to load up my static content.  I leverage C# in my Buisness Logic and Data Access layers which my Page Methods and Web Services call.  So I am not really using much of what makes Web Forms different from MVC.  Also I don't use Session variables.

My only hesitation is that the amount of inline code in the presentation layer feels dirty to me.  It is subjective I know but it reminds me a lot of ASP from the limited exposure I have had to it.  With how popular it seems to be becoming though I might have reached this conclusion through ignorance.

So the question is what would you consider to be the main benefit of choosing one over the other.    Also I primarily write high load database driven web applications.  So scalability, speed, and maintainability are my priorities.

Comment: Have a look at this search. This question has been covered before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+webforms

Comment: Thanks for the additional linkage.  Should have searched first

Comment: @antonlavey, related matches show up right below where you type your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/17/why-i-love-asp.net-mvc.aspx) on the subject. It does a really good job of covering a variety of advantages to using ASP.NET MVC over Webforms.

[Why I love ASP.NET MVC](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/17/why-i-love-asp.net-mvc.aspx)