# Why is ASP.NET MVC more maintainable then Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC versus WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837831/mvc-versus-webforms)

Almost all asp.net mvc vs webforms post I see on SO the selected answer always say ASP.NET mvc is more maintanable but do not give any reasons why. Do you know why MVC is more maintainable then webforms?

Comment: cleaner separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can make web form application maintainable by, for example, using MVP pattern. But most programmers doesn't do that because putting logics all over webform is quick and easy choice. After that programmer got fired or quits, next programmer should follow all the logics to fix a bug in the system. But that creates another bug because test can't be implemented. If the system is complex enough, any change almost guarantees a bug.

MVC doesn't give you that choice for easy path to hell. But this design pattern stuff of ASP.NET MVC is just small part of the story. You can google for the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the argument for ASP.NET MVC being more maintainable than WebForms has to do with the following:

- It cleanly maps to how web requests actually work, instead of shoehorning an eventing model onto the web.
- There are more extensibility points to provide flexibility in solving problems.
- The MVC pattern in general just tends to be more maintainable than a number of things due to the **separation of concerns**.

This is *not* to say however that WebForms cannot be written to be maintainable. There are definitely cleanly written WebForms applications out there, just as there are many cleanly written ASP.NET MVC applications.